# How to filter a dataframe with a special character?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter a column dataframe with a special character '@'(see link). With everything that begins with '@'.

Here is a photo of the dataframe.

[Dataframe with the column 'text'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nULtQ.png)

If anyone has an idea how to do it? I would be thankful

Comment: Please clarify your question. What result do you want to achieve?  Are you trying to *sort* the column (meaning, order the rows in a certain way), or are you trying to *filter* the column (meaning, just get the rows where values begin with `@`), or something else?  Ideally, please [edit] the question to include your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to filter the dataframe by a string column, you can use the `str` attribute:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=["@a", "@c", "@b", "a","d"], columns=["Text"])
df[df.Text.str.startswith("@")]

[output]:
   Text
0   @a
1   @c
2   @b
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain there is a better way, but a work around could be:

```
df['sortme'] = 1
df.loc[df['Text'].str.startswith('@'), 'sortme'] = 0
df.sort_values(['sortme', 'Text'])
```